# "customisation" vs "customization" Which is correct?

Tags: british-english

"customisation" vs "customization" Which is correct?

As per MS Word, customization is correct but Google Chrome correct it to "customisation"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user240918 Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The *s* variant is "Cambridge" spelling, and the *z* variant is "Oxford" spelling. Because Webster adopted the latter, it is the exclusively standard form in the U.S., and perhaps partly on account of this, the former is more popular elsewhere. Looking up either variant in a good dictionary should have been sufficient to answer this question, however.

Comment: It is a continuing irritation to me that the spell-checker used here on SE flags "nominalization" as an error.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization .